# ALTER TABLE ALL TABLES ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

How can I run a command for all tables in a database?

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

I have more than 40000 tables, I want to change them all in one go.

Comment: I would say 40000 tables is a problem that should really be addressed, but if you have that many tables it is probably too late to address that problem without starting over completely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot alter table more than one table per ALTER statement; but you can use a query on `information_schema`.`tables` to generate the alter statements.

Something like

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ROW_FORMAT=fixed;') AS aQuery
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
```

*Keep in mind FIXED is not supported for InnoDB tables, and I am not 100% sure if it can even be explicitly set for MyISAM ones (or is entirely dependent on the table's columns' data types.)*